# How to Add one html file to another html file

Tags: html

i have a header in a separate file with header.html
and i want to include it to another file index.html after head section 
for this i had used

```
<!--#include virtual="header.html"-->
```

and unfortunately it was not running
then i used

```
<!--#include virtual="header.shtml"-->
```

by saving my file as header.shtml

so can anybody please give me any suggestion

Thankyou

**NOTE:I am being using smarty and PHP so using appache server**

Comment: As #include virtual .. is server side includes, which server are you using? There are few server(especially free-webhosts) that do not allow this function.

Comment: sir i am using WAMP server

Answer (score 0):

> [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

OR

> (#include file="footer.html")

OR

$("#header").load("header.html");

Comment: FYI, the last option requires jQuery

Answer (score 0):

- As you are Using **[WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP)** Server, Check whether Your Server **[SSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)**(Server Side Includes) is enabled or not. If not, enable it by editing the configuration file. Following page contains tutorial on **[Setting Up SSI on WAMP](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/php/phpbasics/Setting-Up-SSI-On-Wamp.html)**.
- Use `<!--#include virtual="header.html" -->`

  Instead of

  `<!--#include virtual="header.html"-->`

  **Apache tutorial on SSI stipulates the format requires a space character before the "-->" that closes the element.**
- Also, Where are you adding `<!--#include virtual="header.html" -->` , statement?
  The statement should be within `<html>` tag.

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>My Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

       <!--#include virtual="header.html" -->

   </body>
   </html>
  ```
- Make sure **index.html** and **header.html** files are in Same Directory. If not try to use relative path.
- Following **[page](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html)** contains a lot of issues and common mistakes on **include virtual**   directive.

  ***If it doesn't work at all, then try to go for*** 
  `<?php include("header.html"); ?>` .